# How to access a field of a super-class which is implemented in Java which also has an equal-named method?

Tags: java, scala

I want to extend a class which is implemented in Java. Here is an example:

```
public interface JavaInterface {
    /** Computes foo. */
    public String foo();
}

public class ThisIsJava implements JavaInterface {
    protected String foo = "foo";

    /** Returns value of property foo. */
    public String foo() { return foo; }
}
```

But how do I disambiguate between the field and the method foo when I extend this class in Scala?

```
class ThisIsScala extends ThisIsJava {
  def fooBar = super.foo + "/bar" // doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: Thanks all. I have now changed my Scala code to implement the Java interface directly in order to work around this issue. It seems only reflection would solve it, but that's unacceptable because it's slow and immune to refactorings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access the `foo` field because it's private. You can only access it by `super.foo()`.

Update: I think you have this problem because in Scala there is no distinction between fields and methods, so the only option option would be to have an adapter for ThisIsJava, and extend that adapter in Scala.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: The field has actually protected access. I changed the example accordingly.

Comment: You could also try to use reflections, something like: this.getClass.getDeclaredField("foo").get(this).asInstanceOf[String]

Comment: Ok, thanks, but this comes with a performance penalty and is immune to refactoring.